# convert .shp to .gpx with selected attributes

Tags: qgis, shapefile, convert, attribute-table, gpx

I am working with QGIS 2.6/2.8 (1.8 is installed too).

Right now I am planning an inventory and want to convert a .shp file to a .gpx including the Column "fid" from the attribute table. Is there a way to do it? Or can I copy it later on?

There a more columns in the table of my .shp but I only need the "fid".

Comment: I've voted to close this as a duplicate of a question whose answer allows you to specify fields in a shapefile to values in a gpx. However the FID is a specialized system field that may or may not be useable like that. Furthermore, the FID is somewhat subject to change (for instance when records are removed or replaced) and shouldn't be relied on as a unique identifier - you might want to create your own unique ID field in your shapefile and use that instead, which should work with the answer.